# styling Thunderbird DOM elements: disable color inversion of selected message

Tags: css, dom, themes, customization, thunderbird

In Thunderbird:
For better visual emphasis I have manually added background-colors to my tags via userChrome.css
Therefoe my tagged eMails in my thread pane now have a background-color.

example (yellow tag):

```
/* yellow = 2do*/
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(lc-FFCC33) {background-color:#FFEB33!important}
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(lc-FFCC33) {color:black!important}
```

The problem is: By default, the cursor (i.e. the selected message) looks just the same (white text on blue background-color). In order to distinguish selected messages from tagged messages, I thus have to change the look of the cursor.

My choice for the cursor is: 1px dashed border and no background-color.

```
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected,focus) {
    border: 1px dashed black !important;   
    border-left: 3px solid magenta !important;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;}

#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {background-color:transparent!important}
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {color:inherit!important}
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected,focus) {background-color:transparent!important}
#threadTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected,focus) {color:inherit!important}
```

This prevents the default background-color inversion to blue. For untagged messages the background stays white and for tagged messages the background-color is defined by the tag.

Let's remember: Thunderbird inverts colors for selected messages (white text on blue background). Now that I have disabled the background-color inversion, I'm left with white text on white background.

So I have to prevent Thunderbird from changing the text color of selected messages to white. But how?

I can set `-moz-tree-cell-text color` to black, which brings back the text, but the problem is, it is black for ALL messages. So a tagged message with, say, pink text color (determined by the tag) turns black when selected. But I want it to stay pink when selected:

[image: animation]

I tried various keywords instead of "black", but none of them worked:

```
inherit
initial
currentColor
Highlight
HighlightText
-moz-CellHighlight
-moz-CellHighlightText
-moz-html-CellHighlight
-moz-html-CellHighlightText
-moz-DialogText
```

I also tried `-moz-appearance:none!important` but to no avail.

So my question is:
How can I disable the text color of selected messages (without the aforementioned negative side-effects) ?

Once selected, Thunderbird turns the text color white. So it seems I'd need to

- either tell Thunderbird to use the tag color instead of white,
- or prevent "white" to be assigned in the first place (I thought "inherit" should work, but it doesn't),
- or maybe you know another solution altogether ?

Do you know, how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

PS: Bonus points if you can explain to me, why the border style is lost on the yellow tagged eMail (see animation) and how to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Thunderbird in Manjaro LXQt, the only way to get rid of the black windows was to redefine colors in userChrome.css. So I redefined some treechildren values for the Folder and Thread panes. Then I noticed that tagged messages lost the tag color when selected. By googling I came to this thread (with no solution). Eventually, I did find a way how to preserve the color for tagged messages. However, it assumes using of predetermined color codes.
So, for example, by default the tag "Important" is red (#FF0000). Then I define:
`#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected, lc-FF0000) {`
  `color: #FF0000 !important;`
`}`
It must be after the definition of `#threadTree treechildren:-moz-tree-cell-text(selected)`.